# Getting FileNotFoundError when calling python coded file from robot framework

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework

I am trying to write an automation code for picking up different environment values for execution of my testcases based on the value I pass for environment.

Here is the code I tried :

```
# env.robot

*** Settings ***
Variables      setup.py   stage01

*** Test Cases ***
Print values
    log to console  ${data}
```

```
# setup.py

from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn
import xlrd


def get_variables(env):
    file_location = "values.xlsx"
    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
    sheet = workbook.sheet_by_name(env)
    print("Env : " + sheet.name)
    data = [[sheet.cell_value(r, c) for c in range(sheet.ncols)] for r in range(sheet.nrows)]
    print(data)
    BuiltIn().log_to_console(data)
    return data
```

Response I am getting :

```
[ ERROR ] Error in file 'D:\env.robot': Processing variable file 'D:\setup2.py' with arguments [ stage01 ] 
failed: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'values.xlsx'
```

values.xlsx is present in the same directory with .py and .robot file

I want to get the data from values.xlsx file based on the value of env variable and use the values in robot testcases.

Please suggest what I need to modify or any other approach would also do.

Comment: What do you mean by "the same directory"? Python looks in the current working directory which may be different from where the script is located.

Comment: I mean all the three files (.xlsx, .py and .robot) are located in same folder

Comment: Right, that's not where python looks for relative files. Python will look in the current working directory.